# Finding invariant Borel probability measures for a contraction map

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a contraction map. I need to find all $f$-invariant Borel probability measures.

Thank you.

Comment: Intuitively, since it is a compact metric space,successive applications of f (on a set B=X) will tend to the unique fixed point. Since you want an invariant measure, it has to be supported on that fixed point.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121874/finding-invariant-borel-probability-measures-for-a-contraction-map

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Suppose $\mu$ is $f$-invariant.  Let $B_0 = X$ and $B_{n+1} = f(B_n)$.  Then $\mu(B_n) = 1$ for all $n$.  What can you say about the diameter of $B_n$?  What does this imply about $B := \bigcap_n B_n$?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.